# Network bytes not being registered, but packets are

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, snmp

I have a recently migrated virtual machine (from VMware to KVM) that refuses to internally acknowledge that it is serving and receiving network traffic.

The Networking tab on Task Manager AND Performance Monitor - Networking both show 0 network utilization, but the Local Area Connection interface shows a steady stream of data coming in and out (Sent/Received count grows in real time)

It's as if the system recognises packets, but not bytes, being transfered by the network. It's an issue because our monitoring systems using SNMP uses the byte count to show network connectivity, and thus it assumes the machine isn't active.

By all other accounts it works, as it's currently serving websites. Guessing it might be an issue with changes in devices from the migration, but we have removed all the old network adapters from Vmware to no avail.

Is there any way to trick the system into display data? The machine has been restarted since bring migrated.

Answer (score 3):

The % utilization tab in Task Manager isn't really the place to monitor network traffic in terms of packets sent/received or bytes sent/received. A typical server will have many periods of time where there's no discernable network utilization in Task Manager. The place to monitor actual packets sent/received (per second) and bytes sent/received (per second) is in Performance Monitor. I would suggest adding all of the available counters for the appropriate Network Interface object instance.

In addition, running netstat -s from a command prompt will show you per protocol totals, which are cumulative.

Comment: Perfmon does't show any network utilization either. I was first worried that SNMP wasn't working, but when it's showing the same data from Taskmgr/Perfmon (i.e. 0), then I knew there was a problem. `netstat -s` shows a heap of data, same as the NIC properties. That doesn't really solve the issue of not being able to monitor the network activity in real time.

Comment: In Task Manager on the Networking tab, select View... Select Columns and select Bytes Sent, Bytes Received, and Bytes. This should show you cumaltive numbers. What do you see?

Comment: 0 for both columns.

Comment: Please stop upvoting this answer, it is not the solution, it is just telling me off for using a common network check as a source of the issue.

Comment: An answer doesn't need to be a solution in order to be upvoted. If it were then only one answer per question would ever earn any upvotes. In addition, it's up to the individual to upvote and downvote as they see fit. That being said, you're right in that this is not the solution to your problem.